# How can I center an element in the middle of the viewport?

Tags: html, css

I want to center an element (div, modal/dialog box) in the middle of the viewport, regardless of the page size.

The idea is that the dialog box always appears in the middle of the current view port, so it can be seen by a user regardless of the page size. In my case, I have a very long page with lots of scrolling and if the user is at the bottom of the page and the dialog box appears in the middle of the page it cannot be seen by the user because it is not in his viewport.

My HTML site is run in an iframe, which makes the task even more difficult.

How can I do that with CSS only?

Comment: Try your luck with `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`

Comment: position absolute does not work because I don't want to position it relative to the parent. Fixed does not work either because I want it in the middle of the viewport, not the whole page.

Comment: That is what `position: absolute` is for. To decouple it from its parent elements, unless you explicitly set the parent to `relative`.

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: it is not possible if you are using an iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet.

```css
.modal{
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
    
</div>
```

Well, after you edited the question and mentioned, that the page is in an `iframe`, I can at least say, that it is not possible to place an element inside of an `iframe` to the current viewport of the browser. The most global context of the element is the `iframe` itself, and it has no information about in whatever it is embedded.

Comment: Thank you. Then I know that I cannot do it.

Comment: if you center the iframe itself in its parent viewport, your modal will also be in the center of the main page, somehow. But I don't know how this would be possible in yor specific case.

Answer (score 2):

Apply following CSS

```
.center{
 position: fixed;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Position fixed would make sure it's relative to the viewport. left and top 50% would move the element's top and left to the center. You'd want it to be in the absolute center, it can be done by transform: translate(-50%,-50%);